# Could you please help me with my two concerns regarding this short text

Tags: word-meaning

> " I cannot see how it could assist any state's cause to allow the world to see a man like Alan dying," Barbara Henning said, according to a message released by the UK Foreign Office. ISIS refers to itself as "the Islamic State."

1. I am wondering if you could help me defining the phrase " **how it could assist** " ? Is it an idiom?
2. What does the word **cause** here mean? **any state's cause** ? Could it mean a rule? Or something? I am confused.

Comment: The meaning of cause can easily be looked up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

> " I cannot see **how it could assist** any state's **cause** to allow the world to see a man like Alan dying," Barbara Henning said, according to a message released by the UK Foreign Office. ISIS refers to itself as "the Islamic State."

I'll reply to the simpler question first. *Cause* here means *ideas, goals*, the general *ideology* of a state. The way a state sees itself in the future. The way a state sees a future world, changed through this state's efforts.

[Barbara basically says](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-29299031) that:

1. She understands that the world has a wide variety of states. A state (a country) may have very radical long-term goals and very radical ideology (*cause*).
2. But she doesn't understand how could the publicly displayed murder of a person help any state reach its long-term goals, promote its ideology, implement its plans ( = *assist its cause*).

The phrase **how it could assist** is not an idiom. The word **it** stands for "allowing the world to see a man like Alan dying". To rephrase,

> I cannot see how **allowing the world to see a man like Alan dying** could assist any state's cause.